# Slices return unexpected length

Tags: go

I’m studying Golang and I stopped by this and puzzled me.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    month := [...]string{1: "Jan", 2: "Fab", 3: "March", 4: "April", 5: "May", 6: "June", 7: "July", 8: "Aug", 9: "Sep", 10: "Oct", 11: "Nov", 12: "Dec"}
    fmt.Println(cap(month))
    summer := month[6:9]
    Q2 := month[4:7]
    fmt.Println(cap(Q2))
    fmt.Println(len(Q2))

    fmt.Println(cap(summer))
    fmt.Println(len(summer))
}
```

The Output are

```
13
9
3
7
3
```

Month Slice has 12 elements but the `cap(month)` and `len(month)` return `13`, Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `month` is an **array** – not a slice – and its type is `[13]string`. We know it has 13 elements (the length) just by looking at its type, in contrast to a slice whose type would be `[]string`.

Array and slice indices start at zero, not at one. Since you are not specifying the `string` value at index `0` for the array in:

```
month := [...]string{1: "Jan", 2: "Fab", 3: "March", 4: "April", 5: "May", 6: "June", 7: "July", 8: "Aug", 9: "Sep", 10: "Oct", 11: "Nov", 12: "Dec"}
```

It is equivalent to:

```
month := [13]string{0: "", 1: "Jan", 2: "Fab", 3: "March", 4: "April", 5: "May", 6: "June", 7: "July", 8: "Aug", 9: "Sep", 10: "Oct", 11: "Nov", 12: "Dec"}
```

That is, the *zero value* for `string` (i.e., the empty string) is provided as the first element.

Note that I've replaced `...` with `13`. The ellipsis tells the compiler to deduce the array's length (which is part of its type) based on the initializer.

Even if you had used a slice literal instead of an array literal as the initializer:

```
month := []string{1: "Jan", 2: "Fab", 3: "March", 4: "April", 5: "May", 6: "June", 7: "July", 8: "Aug", 9: "Sep", 10: "Oct", 11: "Nov", 12: "Dec"}
```

The length of (in this case the slice) `month` still will be `13` for the same reason as above.